# How to extract Unicode text from HTML page using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML file(posted below) I need to extract Unicode part from the page. I would like to know how to do it using BeautifulSoup and Python.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<title>
    ലിങ്കണ്‍ വീണ്ടും വെള്ളിത്തിരയില്‍


</head>

<body>

         <div style="float:left;width:95%;">
                <div style="float:right;">
                        <div id="fontsizer"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="article_section">
                                          <div style="float:left;width:100%;padding-bottom:20px;">
                           <div style="float:left;width:320px;">
                          <p class="commontext articlemainheading">ലിങ്കണ്‍ വീണ്ടും വെള്ളിത്തിരയില്‍
</p>
                                                        <p class="commontext leftheadings" style="color:#E73101;">കെ.കെ.ബി.
</p> <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                                      <span style='font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;color:#A5A5A6;float:left;margin-right:5px;'>posted on: </span><p class='labels'>22 Oct 2012</span>                          </div>
                            <a href="mailto:mb4frames@gmail.com"><img src="/movies/images/promo.jpg" style="float:right;margin-top:30px;border:0;"/></a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="commontext bodytext" style="padding-top:10px;" id="storycontent">
                                <div style="float:left;width:100%;font-size:18px;"  id="storycontentfont">
 >
യുനൈറ്റഡ് സ്റ്റേറ്റ്‌സ് ഓഫ് അമേരിക്ക അതിന്റെ 45-ാം പ്രസിഡന്റിനെ തിരഞ്ഞെടുക്കാനുള്ള ഒരുക്കങ്ങളിലാണ്. മുഖ്യഎതിരാളികളായ ബരാക്ക് ഒബാമയും മിറ്റ് റോംനിയും തമ്മിലുള്ള ടെലിവൈസ്ഡ് തര്‍ക്കം അഥവാ വാഗ്വാദങ്ങളാണ് അമേരിക്കന്‍ ടി.വി. പ്രേക്ഷകരുടെ ചര്‍ച്ചാവിഷയം. സാമ്പത്തികവളര്‍ച്ച, തൊഴില്‍നിര്‍മാണം, ആരോഗ്യരക്ഷ എന്നിങ്ങനെയുള്ള വിഷയങ്ങളിലാണ് തര്‍ക്കം. നടപ്പ് പ്രസിഡന്റും വരാനിരിക്കുന്ന (?) പ്രസിഡന്റും തമ്മില്‍ ഈവിധ വിഷയങ്ങളില്‍ ടി.വി.സ്‌ക്രീനില്‍ പരസ്പരം കടിച്ചു കീറുന്ന ആദ്യവട്ട ഡിബേറ്റ് കണ്ട് പ്രേക്ഷകര്‍ ബോറടിച്ച് ചത്തുകൊണ്ടിരിക്കുമ്പോഴാണ് അമേരിക്കയുടെ 16-ാമത്തെ പ്രസിഡന്റ് വെള്ളിത്തിരയിലേക്ക് വന്നത്. <br/>
<br/>
അതെ, അമേരിക്കയുടെ ഏറ്റവും മഹാനായ പ്രസിഡന്റായി ജനം വാഴ്ത്തുന്ന, ഡോളര്‍ നോട്ടുകളുടെയും പെന്നി നാണയങ്ങളുടെയും ഒരു വശത്ത് മുഖം അച്ചടിച്ചുവെച്ചിട്ടുള്ള സാക്ഷാല്‍ അബ്രഹം ലിങ്കണ്‍ തന്നെ സ്‌ക്രീനില്‍. യുനൈറ്റഡ് സ്റ്റേറ്റ്‌സ് തെക്കും വടക്കുമായി വേര്‍തിരിഞ്ഞ് ആഭ്യന്തരയുദ്ധം നടത്തുന്ന കാലത്തെ പ്രസിഡന്റ്. രാജ്യം വിഭജിച്ചുപോകരുത്, അതിനെ ചൊല്ലിയുള്ള യുദ്ധം അവസാനിക്കണം. ഒപ്പം കറുത്ത വര്‍ഗക്കാരെ അടിമകളായി വില്‍ക്കാനും വാങ്ങാനും കൊല്ലാനും വെള്ളക്കാരനുള്ള അവകാശം എന്നെന്നേക്കുമായി ഇല്ലാതാകണം. അത് നിയമവിരുദ്ധമാക്കി മാറ്റുന്ന 13-ാം ഭരണഘടനഭേദഗതി പാസ്സാക്കണം. അതിനുവേണ്ടി അര്‍പ്പണബോധത്തോടെ വാദങ്ങളുയര്‍ത്തുന്ന വെള്ളിത്തിരയിലെ ലിങ്കണെ കണ്ടപ്പോള്‍ നാണയത്തിന്റെ ഒരു വശത്തെ ലിങ്കണെക്കാള്‍ റിയല്‍ വെള്ളിത്തിരയിലെ ലിങ്കണല്ലേ എന്നുപോലും ചിലര്‍ സംശയിച്ചത്രേ. പ്രസിഡന്റാണെങ്കില്‍ ഇങ്ങനെ വേണം ഡയലോഗടിക്കാന്‍ എന്ന് പ്രേക്ഷകര്‍ വിചാരിക്കുന്ന സമയത്താണ് കമേര്‍ഷ്യല്‍ അവസാനിച്ചത്. പരസ്യങ്ങളുടെ ഇടവേളയ്ക്കുശേഷം വരവിന്റെയും ചെലവിന്റെയും വിരസമായ വാദങ്ങളുമായി ഒബാമയും റോംനിയും തിരിച്ചത്തി. <br/>
<br/>
പാവം അമേരിക്കന്‍ പ്രേക്ഷകര്‍ കണ്ടത് അബ്രഹാം ലിങ്കന്റെ അവസാനനാളുകളെ കുറിച്ച് സ്റ്റീഫന്‍സ്പില്‍ബര്‍ഗ് രചിച്ച, അടുത്ത മാസം തിയേറ്ററുകളിലെത്തുന്ന ലിങ്കണ്‍ എന്ന സിനിമയുടെ പരസ്യം മാത്രമാണ്.<br/>
<br/>
സ്റ്റീഫന്‍ സ്പില്‍ബര്‍ഗിനെ ഓര്‍മയില്ലേ? എക്കാലത്തെയും വലിയ ഹിറ്റുകളിലൊന്നായി കൂട്ടുന്ന 'ജാസ്' എന്ന ചിത്രവുമായി 30-ാമത്തെ വയസ്സില്‍ ജനശ്രദ്ധയിലെത്തിയശേഷം വര്‍ഷങ്ങളോളം വിജയത്തിന്റെ ജൈത്രയാത്ര മാത്രം നടത്തിയ സംവിധായകന്‍. സ്പില്‍ബര്‍ഗന്നെ പേര് കേട്ടാല്‍ മനസ്സിലെക്കോടിവരുന്ന എത്രയോ സിനിമകളും കഥാപാത്രങ്ങളുമുണ്ട് -ഇ.ടി. ദ എക്‌സ്ട്രാടെറസ്ട്രിയല്‍, ഇന്‍ഡ്യാന ജോണ്‍സ്, ദിനസോറുകളെ സാധാരണക്കാര്‍ക്കു കൂടി പരിചിത മൃഗമാക്കിയ ജുറാസ്സിക് പാര്‍ക്ക്, ഷിന്‍ഡ്‌ലേഴ്‌സ് ലിസ്റ്റ്..... അദ്ദേഹത്തിന്റെ ചിത്രങ്ങളെല്ലാം കൂടി ലോകത്തെല്ലായിടത്തുനിന്നുമായി 850 കോടിഡോളര്‍ (ഏതാണ്ട് 42,500 കോടി രൂപ) നേടി എന്നാണ് കണക്ക്. സംവിധായകനും തിരക്കഥാകൃത്തുമായി തുടങ്ങിയ സ്പില്‍ബര്‍ഗ് നാല് പതിറ്റാണ്ട് കഴിയുമ്പോഴേയ്ക്കും നിര്‍മാതാവും വ്യവസായിയും ശതകോടീശ്വരനുമൊക്കെയായി മാറി. <br/>
 <div align='center'><img src='http://images.mathrubhumi.com/images/2012/Oct/22/03089_439148.jpg' border='0px'/></div><br/>
എങ്കിലും അദ്ദേഹം സിനിമ ഉപേക്ഷിച്ചിട്ടില്ല. ഒരിക്കല്‍ വാണിജ്യവിജയത്തിന്റെ ഉദാത്ത മാതൃകകളായ ചിത്രങ്ങളെടുത്ത സംവിധായകന്‍ കലാമൂല്യമുള്ള ചിത്രങ്ങളിലേക്ക് ശ്രദ്ധ തിരിച്ചു - അതിന്റെ ഫലമാണ് ഷിന്‍ഡ്‌ലേഴ്‌സ് ലിസ്റ്റും സേവിങ്ങ് പ്രൈവറ്റ് റയാനും അമിസ്റ്റാഡും പോലുള്ള രചനകള്‍. അവയും അപ്രതീക്ഷിതമായ വാണിജ്യവിജയങ്ങള്‍ നേടിയപ്പോള്‍ കലയും കച്ചവടവും സംയോജിപ്പിക്കാന്‍ കഴിവുള്ളവന്‍ എന്ന പ്രശസ്തി കൂടി അദ്ദേഹം കരസ്ഥമാക്കി.<br/>
<br/>
അദ്ദേഹത്തിന്റെ ഹിറ്റായ ഒടുവിലത്തെ ചിത്രം 2008-ല്‍ റിലീസ് ചെയ്ത ഇന്‍ഡ്യാന ജോണ്‍സ് ആന്‍ഡ് ദ ക്രിസ്റ്റല്‍ സ്‌കള്‍ ആയിരുന്നു. ചിത്രം സാമ്പത്തിക വിജയമായിരുന്നെങ്കിലും ഇന്‍ഡ്യാന പരമ്പരയിലെ നാലാം ചിത്രം എന്ന മാധ്യമശ്രദ്ധയെ പിടിച്ചുപറ്റിയുള്ളൂ. പൊതുവെ സ്പില്‍ബര്‍ഗ് എന്ന പേരിനുണ്ടായിരുന്ന മാജിക് പരിവേഷം മാഞ്ഞ് മാഞ്ഞില്ലാതാകുന്ന കാലമാണിത്. എന്നാല്‍ ഈ മാസം ന്യൂയോര്‍ക്ക് ഫിലിം ഫെസ്റ്റിവലില്‍ വെച്ച് ലിങ്കന്റെ പ്രിവ്യൂ കാണാന്‍ കഴിഞ്ഞവരുടെ അഭിപ്രായം വെച്ച് ഈ ചിത്രം സ്പില്‍ബര്‍ഗനെ വീണ്ടും വെള്ളിവെളിച്ചത്തിലെത്തിക്കും. അടുത്ത ഓസ്‌കര്‍ ദിനത്തില്‍ അനേകം അവാര്‍ഡുകള്‍ ലിങ്കണ്‍ കരസ്ഥമാക്കുമെന്നാണ് ചിലരെങ്കിലും പറയുന്നത്.<br/>
<br/>
ചലച്ചിത്ര നിരീക്ഷകര്‍ ഇങ്ങനെ നിരീക്ഷിക്കുന്നതില്‍ അത്ഭുതമില്ല. കാരണം ഈ ചിത്രത്തില്‍ ഹോളിവുഡിലെ ഹെവി വെയ്റ്റുകളെ എമ്പാടും കാണാം. അബ്രഹാം ലിങ്കണായി വേഷമിടുന്നത് രണ്ടുതവണ ബെസ്റ്റ് ആക്ടര്‍ ഓസ്‌കര്‍ നേടിയ ഡാനിയേല്‍ ഡേ ലൂയിസ് ആണെങ്കില്‍ ലിങ്കണെ എതിര്‍ക്കുകയും ഒപ്പം സഹായിക്കുകയും ചെയ്യുന്ന റിപ്പബ്ലിക്കന്‍ സെനറ്റര്‍ തദേയുസ് സ്റ്റീവന്‍സിന്റെ വേഷമണിയുന്ന ടോമി ലീ ജോണ്‍സും മൂന്നുതവണ ഓസ്‌കര്‍ നോമിനേഷന്‍ നേടുകയും ഒരു വട്ടം ബെസ്റ്റ് സപ്പോര്‍ട്ടിങ്ങ് ആക്ടര്‍ അവാഡ് നേടുകയും ചെയ്തിട്ടുണ്ട്.</span></div>                                </div>

                                                                    <div style="float:left;width:606px;background:#F2F2F2;padding:10px 0px 5px 0px;border:1px solid #DFDFDF;margin-top:10px;display:inline;" class="ajaxpagination">
                                        <div style="float:right;margin-right:10px;">&nbsp;<b>1</b>&nbsp;<a href="#storycontent"  class='lastlink' onclick="DoAction('/movies/welcome/story/hollywood/311364/11000',11000,'storycontent')">2</a>&nbsp;<a href="#storycontent"  class='ajaxlinks' onclick="DoAction('/movies/welcome/story/hollywood/311364/11000',11000,'storycontent')">NEXT</a>&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>

                          </div>


                               </div>
```

I need to get this
റ്റീഫന്‍ സ്പില്‍ബര്‍ഗിനെ ഓര്‍മയില്ലേ? എക്കാലത്തെയും വലിയ ഹിറ്റുകളിലൊന്നായി കൂട്ടുന്ന 'ജാസ്' എന്ന ചിത്രവുമായി 30-ാമത്തെ വയസ്സില്‍ ജനശ്രദ്ധയിലെത്തിയശേഷം വര്‍ഷങ്ങളോളം വിജയത്തിന്റെ ജൈത്രയാത്ര മാത്രം നടത്തിയ സംവിധായകന്‍. സ്പില്‍ബര്‍ഗന്നെ പേര് കേട്ടാല്‍ മനസ്സിലെക്കോടിവരുന്ന എത്രയോ സിനിമകളും കഥാപാത്രങ്ങളുമുണ്ട് -ഇ.ടി. ദ എക്‌സ്ട്രാടെറസ്ട്രിയല്‍, ഇന്‍ഡ്യാന ജോണ്‍സ്, ദിനസോറുകളെ സാധാരണക്കാര്‍ക്കു കൂടി പരിചിത മൃഗമാക്കിയ ജുറാസ്സിക് പാര്‍ക്ക്, ഷിന്‍ഡ്‌ലേഴ്‌സ് ലിസ്റ്റ്..... അദ്ദേഹത്തിന്റെ ചിത്രങ്ങളെല്ലാം കൂടി ലോകത്തെല്ലായിടത്തുനിന്നുമായി 850 കോടിഡോളര്‍ (ഏതാണ്ട് 42,500 കോടി രൂപ) നേടി എന്നാണ് കണക്ക്. സംവിധായകനും തിരക്കഥാകൃത്തുമായി തുടങ്ങിയ സ്പില്‍ബര്‍ഗ് നാല് പതിറ്റാണ്ട് കഴിയുമ്പോഴേയ്ക്കും നിര്‍മാതാവും വ്യവസായിയും ശതകോടീശ്വരനുമൊക്കെയായി മാറി.
This is the link of the website http://www.mathrubhumi.com/story.php?id=397475

my code:

```
import os
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url= "http://www.mathrubhumi.com/sports/story.php?id=397111"
raw = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw)
article = soup.get_text
```

Comment: Can you proivide a link to the webpage?

Comment: http://www.mathrubhumi.com/story.php?id=397475

Comment: @justhalf. I am not able to extract Unicode text. Instead of that I am getting full HTML and Java Scripts.

Comment: @justhalf Yes. Thanks. How to write this to a text file?

Comment: @justhalf, Yes it is working fine

Comment: @justhalf. I am getting an error  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/extract_web.py", line 20, in <module>
    out.write(result,)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 21-30: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import os
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url= "http://www.mathrubhumi.com/sports/story.php?id=397111"
raw = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw,'lxml')
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)

def contains_unicode(text):
    try:
        str(text)
    except:
        return True
    return False

result = ''.join((text for text in texts if contains_unicode(text)))

# Output to a file
with open('output.txt','w') as out:
    out.write(result)
```

will output:

```
  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  പാവപ്പെട്ട കുട്ടികള്ക്ക് ബ്രെറ്റ്ലീയുടെ വിദ്യാഭ്യാസ ബസ്ജ്വാലാ ഗുട്ടയ്ക്ക് ഡെന്മാര്ക്ക് ഓപ്പണില് പങ്കെടുക്കാംരഞ്ജി ട്രോഫി: സച്ചിന് ബേബി കേരള ടീം ക്യാപ്റ്റന്ഇന്ത്യ-ഓസ്ട്രേലിയ ട്വന്റി 20 മത്സരം ഇന്ന്ഫെഡറേഷന് കപ്പ് ജനവരി ഒന്നുമുതല് ദുലീപ് ട്രോഫി സെമി ഇന്നുമുതല്വിന്ഡീസ് എ 268ന് പുറത്ത് മുഖം മിനുക്കി ബാംഗ്ലൂര് എഫ്.സി.  അരങ്ങേറ്റം ഉജ്ജ്വലമാക്കി ഈസ്റ്റ്ബംഗാള് ജ്വാല കോടതിയിലേക്ക്  റാത്തോഡിന്റെ മകന് വെങ്കലം, ഇന്ത്യയ്ക്ക് മെഡല് കൊയ്ത്ത് ഷറപ്പോവയ്ക്ക് പരിക്ക് ദില്ഷന് ടെസ്റ്റ് മതിയാക്കുന്നു ടോറസ്സിന്റെ രക്ഷപ്പെടല്:  നിയമം കര്ശനമാക്കണം - ഡൈക്ക് മിനെയ്റോയ്ക്ക്  അര ലക്ഷം ഡോളര് പിഴ പന്തില് കൃത്രിമം; ക്യാപ്റ്റന് കുടുങ്ങും കുട്ടിക്രിക്കറ്റില് ഇന്ത്യ ഇന്ത്യ-ഉസ്ബെക്ക് മത്സരം ഇന്ന് ലോക സ്കൂള്മീറ്റ്: ഷില്ബിയുടെ ട്രാക്കില് ദാരിദ്ര്യത്തിന്റെ കിതപ്പ് ഹോം  വാര്ത്തകള്

അഭിമുഖംക്രിക്കറ്റ് ഫുട്ബോള് മറ്റു മത്സരങ്ങള് ടെന്നീസ് ഹെല്ത്തിട്രാക്ക്ജീവിതരേഖലേഖനങ്ങള്റൈറ്റ്ട്രാക്ക്സ്റ്റാര്ഫോക്കസ്വാര്ത്തകള്നൊസ്റ്റാള്ജിയചരിത്രംആത്മകഥവെബ്സ്പെഷ്യല് ശ്രീനിക്ക് പച്ചക്കൊടി
 * ബി.സി.സി.ഐ. പ്രസിഡന്റായി ചുമതലയേല്ക്കാം
* അന്വേഷണത്തില് ഇടപെടരുത് മൂന്നംഗ സുപ്രീംകോടതി സമിതി നിലവില്
* റിപ്പോര്ട്ട് നാല് മാസത്തിനകം
ന്യൂഡല്ഹി: വാതുവെപ്പ് ഉള്പ്പെടെ ഐ.പി.എല്ലുമായി ബന്ധപ്പെട്ട വിഷയങ്ങളില് ഒരുതരത്തിലും ഇടപെടില്ലെന്ന വ്യവസ്ഥയില് ഇന്ത്യന് ക്രിക്കറ്റ് കണ്ട്രോള് ബോര്ഡിന്റെ (ബി.സി.സി.ഐ.) പ്രസിഡന്റ് പദവിയേറ്റെടുക്കാന് എന്. ശ്രീനിവാസന് സുപ്രീംകോടതി അനുമതി നല്കി. ഐ.പി.എല്. വാതുവെപ്പിനെക്കുറിച്ച് അന്വേഷിക്കാന് രൂപം നല്കിയ മൂന്നംഗ സമിതിയെയും കോടതി പ്രഖ്യാപിച്ചു.
പഞ്ചാബ് - ഹരിയാണ ഹൈക്കോടതി ചീഫ് ജസ്റ്റിസായിരുന്ന മുകുള് മുദ്ഗല് അധ്യക്ഷനും അഡീഷണല് സോളിസിറ്റര് ജനറല് എല്. നാഗേശ്വര റാവു, മുതിര്ന്ന അഭിഭാഷകന് നിലയ് ദത്ത എന്നിവരടങ്ങുന്ന മൂന്നംഗ സമിതിയെയാണ് ഐ.പി.എല്. വാതുവെപ്പ് അന്വേഷിക്കുന്നതിന് കോടതി നിയോഗിച്ചത്. തുടര്ന്ന് ശ്രീനിവാസന് ചുമതലയേല്ക്കുന്നതിന് നിലനിന്നിരുന്ന വിലക്ക് ജസ്റ്റിസുമാരായ എ.കെ. പട്നായിക്, ജെ. എസ്. കേഹര് എന്നിവരടങ്ങിയ ബെഞ്ച് നീക്കി. അന്വേഷണത്തില് ഒരു തരത്തിലും ഇടപെടരുതെന്ന് വ്യക്തമാക്കിയ കോടതി, സമിതി ആവശ്യപ്പെടുന്ന എല്ലാ സഹായങ്ങളും നല്കണമെന്നും നിര്ദേശിച്ചിട്ടുണ്ട്. നാല് മാസത്തിനുള്ളില് അന്വേഷണ റിപ്പോര്ട്ട് സുപ്രീംകോടതിക്ക് സമര്പ്പിക്കണം.
മൂന്നംഗ സമിതിയെ തിങ്കളാഴ്ച കോടതി നിര്ദേശിച്ചിരുന്നു. ഇതിനോട് ഹര്ജിക്കാരായ ബി.സി.സി.ഐ.യും ബിഹാര് ക്രിക്കറ്റ് അസോസിയേഷനും യോജിച്ചു. ചെന്നൈ സൂപ്പര് കിങ്സിന്റെ മുഖ്യ ചുമതലക്കാരനായിരുന്ന ശ്രീനിവാസന്റെ മരുമകന് ഗുരുനാഥ് മെയ്യപ്പന്, രാജസ്ഥാന് റോയല്സിന്റെ ഉടമസ്ഥര് എന്നിവര്ക്കെതിരെയുള്ള ആരോപണങ്ങളാണ് സമിതി അന്വേഷിക്കുന്നത്.
അന്വേഷണത്തില് ഇടപെടില്ലെന്ന് ശ്രീനിവാസന്തന്നെയാണ് കോടതിയില് പറഞ്ഞതെന്ന് ബി.സി.സി.ഐ.യുടെ അഭിഭാഷകന് സി. അരയാമ സുന്ദരം വിശദീകരിച്ചു. കോടതിവിധി ബി.സി.സി.ഐ.യ്ക്കോ ശ്രീനിവാസനോ തിരിച്ചടിയല്ലെന്ന് അദ്ദേഹം അവകാശപ്പെട്ടു.
ഐ.പി.എല്. വാതുവെപ്പ് അന്വേഷിക്കുന്നതിന് ബി.സി.സി.ഐ. നിര്ദേശിച്ച സമിതിയെ കഴിഞ്ഞദിവസം സുപ്രീംകോടതി തള്ളിക്കളഞ്ഞിരുന്നു. വാതുവെപ്പ് അന്വേഷിക്കുന്നതിന് അരുണ് ജെയ്റ്റ്ലിയും നിലയ് ദത്തയുമടങ്ങുന്നതായിരുന്നു ഈ സമിതി. മുംബൈ പോലീസിന്റെ കുറ്റപത്രത്തില് പറയുന്ന കാര്യങ്ങള് അന്വേഷിക്കേണ്ടതുണ്ടോയെന്ന് സമിതി പരിശോധിക്കുമെന്ന നിലപാടിലായിരുന്നു ബി.സി.സി.ഐ. എന്നാല്, സുപ്രീംകോടതി രണ്ട് നിര്ദേശങ്ങളും തള്ളി.
ബി.സി.സി.ഐ. നേരത്തേ, നിയമിച്ച രണ്ടംഗ അന്വേഷണ കമ്മീഷന് ഭരണഘടനാ വിരുദ്ധവും നിയമവിരുദ്ധവുമാണെന്ന് മുംബൈ ഹൈക്കോടതി വിധിച്ചിരുന്നു. ഈ കമ്മീഷന് മെയ്യപ്പനെയും രാജസ്ഥാന് റോയല്സ് ഉടമ രാജ് കുന്ദ്രയെയും കുറ്റവിമുക്തരായി പ്രഖ്യാപിച്ചിരുന്നു. മുംബൈ കോടതി വിധിക്കെതിരെ നല്കിയ അപ്പീലിലും ബി.സി.സി.ഐ.യ്ക്ക് അനുകൂല വിധി കിട്ടിയില്ല. ബി.സി.സി.ഐ. വിരുദ്ധ നിലപാടുള്ള ബിഹാര് ക്രിക്കറ്റ് അസോസിയേഷന് ഈ കേസ്സില് കക്ഷി ചേര്ന്നിരുന്നു.
    മുംബൈ കോടതിവിധിയുടെ പശ്ചാത്തലത്തില് പുതിയ അന്വേഷണം വേണമെന്നായിരുന്നു ബിഹാര് അസോസിയേഷന്റെ ആവശ്യം.
സപ്തംബര് 29-ന് നടന്ന തിരഞ്ഞെടുപ്പില് ബി.സി.സി.ഐ. പ്രസിഡന്റായി തിരഞ്ഞെടുക്കപ്പെട്ടിരുന്നെങ്കിലും കോടതി നിര്ദേശം വരുന്നതുവരെ പദവിയേറ്റെടുക്കരുതെന്ന് സുപ്രീം കോടതി നിര്ദേശിച്ചിരുന്നു. പ്രസിഡന്റ് സ്ഥാനം ഏറ്റെടുക്കാനുള്ള കോടതിയുടെ അനുമതിയെ ബി.സി.സി.ഐ. സ്വാഗതം ചെയ്തു.
സന്തോഷം
ബി.സി.സി.ഐ. അധ്യക്ഷനായി ചുമതലയേല്ക്കുന്നതിന് സുപ്രീംകോടതി നല്കിയ അനുമതിയില് എന്. ശ്രീനിവാസന് സന്തോഷം പ്രകടിപ്പിച്ചു. ബോര്ഡിന്റെ ദൈനംദിന പ്രവര്ത്തനങ്ങള് നോക്കാന് ആരെങ്കിലും വേണ്ടേ? അതുകൊണ്ടാണ് അനുകൂല വിധിയുണ്ടായതെന്നും മാധ്യമപ്രവര്ത്തകരെ അഭിമുഖീകരിക്കവേ അദ്ദേഹം പറഞ്ഞു.രഞ്ജി ട്രോഫി: സച്ചിന് ബേബി കേരള ടീം ക്യാപ്റ്റന്
ജ്വാലാ ഗുട്ടയ്ക്ക് ഡെന്മാര്ക്ക് ഓപ്പണില് പങ്കെടുക്കാം
പാവപ്പെട്ട കുട്ടികള്ക്ക് ബ്രെറ്റ്ലീയുടെ വിദ്യാഭ്യാസ ബസ്
ലോക സ്കൂള്മീറ്റ്: ഷില്ബിയുടെ ട്രാക്കില് ദാരിദ്ര്യത്തിന്റെ കിതപ്പ്
മുഖം മിനുക്കി ബാംഗ്ലൂര് എഫ്.സി.
വിന്ഡീസ് 'എ' 268ന് പുറത്ത്
റാത്തോഡിന്റെ മകന് വെങ്കലം, ഇന്ത്യയ്ക്ക് മെഡല് കൊയ്ത്ത്
ടോറസ്സിന്റെ രക്ഷപ്പെടല്:  നിയമം കര്ശനമാക്കണം - ഡൈക്ക്
മിനെയ്റോയ്ക്ക്  അര ലക്ഷം ഡോളര് പിഴ
ഷറപ്പോവയ്ക്ക് പരിക്ക്
»
        © Copyright   2013  Mathrubhumi. All rights reserved.
```